# Regaining control in codename one app after delegating to native app

Tags: codenameone

I'm delegating from a codename one app to the native email app. I was expecting this call to send the codename one app to background, or at least stop further code execution util the control is being recovered, however this is not happening. No lifecyle method ( stop/start ) is beeing called and code following the delegation is still being executed.

I want to stop all execution in the codename one app until after the user finished with the email app, and then be notified in some way when the codename one app regained control.

I'm sure there should be a simple, straightforward way to do this, however I cannot find it.

Please help!

I would prefer not to force the app to minimize if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stop()` and `start()` should be invoked when moving to the other app but they will be invoked asynchronously on the EDT so assuming your code looks like this pseudo code:

```
callNativeEmailApp();
doSomeStuff();
```

Then `doSomeStuff()` will happen right away and `stop()` won't be invoked yet because it's still waiting on the EDT thread.  You can give `stop()` a chance to get invoked by using:

```
callNativeEmailApp();
Display.getInstance().callSerially(() -> doSomeStuff());
```

But that might be problematic as it relies on minor platform behaviors, starting the email app might take a while and calling `stop()` might happen only when the email app gains control.

A better approach is to do something like this:

```
setFlagThatWeShouldBeInEmailApp();
callNativeEmailApp();
```

Then in `stop()` and `start()` you can test such flags and write the logic there. Notice that this is "fragile" as you would need to deal with the case of a crash or cancellation.

Comment: Actully, it's quite strage, because I've removed any code following native email app delegation but the stop() and start() are not being called. The email app opens, but when going back to the codename one app it behaves like nothing happened. Is this expected behaviour ? Is it guaranteed the the app is beeing put to sleep during delegation to a native app ?

I'm testing the app on a Lenove K6 Note with Android 6.0.1.

Comment: It should be guaranteed that `stop()` & `start()` are invoked in this case. I suggest using logging to verify that this is indeed the case. Notice the code at the start of the `start()` method might disrupt your app logic as it will show the last active form. You need to be careful of this behavior.

Comment: If I'm manually minimizing the app, stop()/start() are being called and the application resumes successfully. However, after delegating to the native email app, there is no sign that the codename one app is being put to sleep. I'm pretty sure that it's not going through stop()/start() cycle. Could this be a bug, or some weird behaviour resulted from the phone/platform/code combination that I'm using ?

Comment: It could be a bug and it could be a platform "misbehavior" that we don't have a workaround for. The problem is that these sort of behaviors are notoriously hard to debug so if you have a workaround approach I would suggest taking that.